# Solving a system of Transcendental equations

Tags: systems-of-equations, nonlinear-system, math-software, transcendental-equations

I am trying to find the maximum value of $\lambda$, where 0 $\le$ $\lambda$ $\le$ 90$^\circ$
In the following system of equations $\lambda$, E, $\phi$ are my variables and rest all are arbitrary constants.

Following variables are defined for the sake of simplifying the main equations
$$x = a \cos(E) cos\Omega + a \sin(E) sin\Omega$$
$$y = - a \cos(E) \sin(\Omega) \cos(I) + a \sin(E) \cos\Omega \cos(I)$$
$$z = [N (1 - e^2) + h] \sin\lambda$$

The system of equations are as follows:

$$(N + h) \cos\lambda\cos\phi = x \cos\theta_0 + y \sin\theta_0$$
$$(N + h) \cos\lambda \sin\phi = -x \sin\theta_0 + y \cos\theta_0$$
$$y D \cos\epsilon + z D \sin\epsilon - a^2\ge a \cos\theta\sqrt{a^2 + D^2 - 2D(y\cos\epsilon +z\sin\epsilon)}$$

Comment: You can't subsitute functions of a variable and then mix the substitution with the actual variable (like you are doing with $z$ and $\lambda$): that isn't simplifying anything, but only hiding a piece of the problem under the carpet in the hope that you might be lulled into forgetting about it.

Comment: Please rewrite the system in terms of $\lambda,E,\phi$, while combining all constants that can.

Comment: As $\lambda$ appears as the argument of trigonometric functions, it does not have a maximum.

Comment: @Gae.S. I wasn't trying to hide a piece of problem, I am trying to maximise my $\lambda$ and I only had my conditional equation in terms of x, y and z. So I wrote x, y and z as a function of $\lambda$ and other variables so that I can express my conditional equation in terms of my desired variable

Comment: @YvesDaoust I forgot to mention the domain of $\lambda$, I have made the required edits in the question

Comment: @YvesDaoust I don't think so, there will be a single maximum value of $\lambda$ in that range.

Comment: @YvesDaoust there should be 2 solutions if I am correct, one positive and one negative

Comment: @YvesDaoust I am really sorry I misunderstood your question, There will be a range of values of $\lambda$ starting from a negative value to a maximum value. There is a constraint on the maximum value $\lambda_{max} \ge -\epsilon$ which I found running a simulation. It need not be positive always.